# How can I graph the bias voltage vs capacitance in ADS?

Tags: voltage, simulation, capacitance, graph, ads

[image]

I am trying to model a bias tee and control the capacitance of the varactor by varying the voltage.

How do I plot the voltage vs capacitance/charge in a graph in ADS using AC simulation?

Comment: I am confused. You seem to be using the NonlinC component, described here: https://edadocs.software.keysight.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5911555. It looks like the relationship between voltage and capacitance is defined explicitly by the coefficient list in the schematic. In this case you have capacitance is equal to $$C(V) = 0 + V + 3V^2 + 2V^3$$ Not sure if there is a way to obtain this graph in ADS, but you can throw the equation into your favorite plotting software/website to get a plot...

Comment: Yes I am using the nonlinear cap instead of a varactor. I need to check the change in capacitance with the bias voltage. YOU mean there is no option to get the capacitance plot?

Comment: I am not very familiar with ADS, so I don't know (maybe someone else can answer). But I am not sure what you need to check, since the relationship between voltage and capacitance is known precisely. Like I said, if you need a plot, you can just plot it yourself like this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mnky2rsbli The Y-axis is capacitance and X-axis is voltage.

Comment: Thank you @mooshoomatt. I will try that as you said